# How to get value of async JSONP request?

Tags: javascript

I need to receive a value of JSONP async request. When I assigning "data" to global variable, I receive a empty object. Please, help me.

Now, I my code get

```
var url = "http://local/main/getEventData/" + event_id;
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('src', url);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

var event_data = {};

function callback(data) {
    event_data = data;
}
```

and JSONP

```
callback({name: 'John'})
```

PS Request absolutely works and I can display data variable via console.log(data)

Comment: That isn't JSON-P. JSON-P would be: `callback({"name": "John"})`. Property names must be strings (not identifiers) and strings must be quoted using `"` not `'`.

Comment: How do you know you "receive an empty object"? When are you testing event_data? Could you be reading it too soon?

Comment: @Quentin: That's unnecessary quibbling - JSONP is getting executed, and in JavaScript code `{name: 'John'}` is valid without the quotes as long as the name part obeys certain restrictions. Sure it is not JSON by spec, but it should work.

Comment: Amadan, I'm just do "console.log(event_data);"

Comment: @Quentin while you're of course correct about the invalid JSON, for JSONP (as it currently exists) it's not even possible to enforce that rule, right?  JavaScript parsers don't have any idea that they're supposed to reject invalid JSON; indeed there's nothing preventing the JSON from containing function calls etc.

Comment: @Amadan — That's why it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Pointy — Not if it is being loaded via a `<script>` element. There might be something out there which strips the function call and then parses as JSON. Whether or not there is, however, there isn't any reason not to do things the right way.

Comment: @NiLL: I know you're doing `console.log(event_data)`; the million-dollar question is *when*. You might be inspecting it before the call goes through.

Comment: @Quentin fair enough :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the data when you get it, not (as I assume you are trying now) as soon as you're requested it.

```
function callback(data) {
    event_data = data;
    // Now you have the data, do something with it.
}

// Don't try to use event_data here. There's no way 
// to know if the callback has fired yet
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've got will work just fine. You'll just have to put the code (or a call to a function, or whatever) **inside** your "callback" function so that the code doesn't run until the script is retrieved.